# How do you learn about CMOS sensors supporting circuitry

Tags: image-sensor

I want to get some resources about CMOS sensors circuitry - less about the sensors themselves and more about how to build supporting circuitry for them.

I couldn't find any reference designs (Do sensor manufacturers supply reference module designs for their products?), books or actually anything related to that.

Adittionally, it's very difficult to find datasheets for sensors from manufacturers (e.g OmniVision), what am I missing here? Do I need to contact the manufacturers for that?

Comment: Presumably you're talking about image sensors and not chemical, gas or some other kind of sensor?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany see tag.

Comment: The only "support circuitry" for image sensors I know is the receive interface, which is normally according to a standard. MIPI CSI springs to mind. You must try to get a datasheet and OmniVision will not talk to you unless you buy at least 4 or 5 million.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the Journal of Solid State Circuits in your library; its from the IEEE Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers. Some issues form 2000 and 2005 and 2010 would have an article on imagers and their CMOS circuits, nearly every month. Ditto for the Systems and Circuits  (or is it Circuits and Systems?) journal.